# Firebase - Share authentication across sub domains using firebase admin sdk

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have done some research about sharing the `auth object` across sub domains of my app. Apparently firebase's web sdk this setup.

My idea is to have a single login website `login.myapp.com` which can be used by my other apps `app1.myapp.com`, `app2.myapp.com` to authenticate with. Just like google.

My first attempt was to `stringify()` the auth object from `localStorage`, then send it as a url param to the requesting app so that I could `parse()` the auth object and store it to that app's `localStorage`.

But I dont like this setup, not only the tokens will be recorded on browser's history, it also looks weird.

So I was wondering if there is a known setup for this using the admin sdk.

1. Get auth from `login.myapp.com`
2. Pass the `uid` to `app1.myapp.com`
3. `app1.myapp.com` pass the `uid` to server via http
4. The server will check if the `uid` is authenticated.
5. If successful, the server will respond an `auth object` to `app1.myapp.com`.

Can the firebase admin produce something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like custom token minting is what you need. How about you [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) in `login.myapp.com` using an Admin SDK, and then pass it to your requesting apps? These apps can then login to Firebase by calling [`signInWithCustomToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients).

Comment: Whoah! Thanks Hiranya. :) I'll come back here to accept your answer once I tested it.

Comment: How do we pass the custom token to the requesting app?

Comment: Hey Hiranya, say user logged in from login.myapp.com, when navigating to app1.myapp.com, does he/she need to call login again? I think it should automatically log user in.